# Can the CASE function be improved?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am trying to get a message from the database to see if an order was delivered on time or not. I am repeating a piece of code multiple times inside the 'CASE' function.

**Can it be improved/optimized?**

```
SELECT (CASE 
          WHEN ROUND((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(orders.delivered_at) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(orders.created_at, INTERVAL (order.time) + 25) MINUTE)))/60) > 0 
            THEN CONCAT('Order delivered with ', ROUND((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(orders.delivered_at) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(orders.created_at, INTERVAL (order.time) + 25) MINUTE)))/60), ' minutes delay.') 
          WHEN ROUND((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(orders.delivered_at) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(orders.created_at, INTERVAL (order.time) + 25) MINUTE)))/60) < 0 
            THEN CONCAT('Order delivered ', ABS(ROUND((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(orders.delivered_at) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(orders.created_at, INTERVAL (order.time) + 25) MINUTE)))/60)), ' minutes faster.')
          ELSE 'Order delivered on time.' 
        END ) as message
FROM orders;
```

Here is the table schema:

```
+----------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------+
| order_id | created_at          | delivered_at         | time (minutes) |
+----------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------+
| 1        | 2020-04-13 10:10:00 | 2020-04-13 12:30:00  | 20             |
+----------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------+
| 2        | 2020-04-13 14:20:00 | 2020-04-13 14:50:00  | 30             |
+----------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------+
```

For the first order, the result should be *"Order delayed with 95 minutes."*,
and for the second one *"Order delivered 25 minutes faster."*.

The time difference between when an order was actually delivered and when it should have been delivered is calculated like this: orders.delivered_at - (orders.created_at + time + 25)

The query returns the correct data, but can it be IMPROVED? Can I do sth in order not to repeat the "ROUND((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(...." duplicated code?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and the logic you want to implement.

Comment: What datatype is `order.time`?  If it is `TIME`, your expressions are _wrong_.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: order.time is an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the difference in minutes aliased from a subquery and use it like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN o.diff > 0 THEN CONCAT('Order delivered with ', o.diff, ' minutes delay.') 
    WHEN o.diff < 0 THEN CONCAT('Order delivered ', ABS(o.diff), ' minutes faster.')
    ELSE 'Order delivered on time.' 
  END as message
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ROUND((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(orders.delivered_at) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(orders.created_at, INTERVAL (orders.time) + 25 MINUTE)))/60)   as diff
  FROM orders
) as o
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v9zYjYhuBitd3a6hh1eMVN/0).
Results:

```
| message                                |
| -------------------------------------- |
| Order delivered with 95 minutes delay. |
| Order delivered 25 minutes faster.     |
```

Comment: Tnx. Can this be used with joins also? If yes, what's the syntax?

Comment: Joins are used to link tables or queries. In this case you have only 1 table and there is no need for joins.

Comment: I know that. It was just a hypothetical question. Let's say I want to join a users table with the orders one, is this possible with this query? Or it should be changes completely?

Comment: Change completely? No. As you can see in my code I use  a query inside `FROM (....)`. So if you put your new query there inside the parentheses you can do something similar.

Comment: Okay. I understand. Thank you :)